# Sharepoint Subsite CEWP Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

So I have a sharepoint site that has a subsite that keeps throwing the error :

> One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format.
>   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation cannot deserialize the Web Part. 
>   Check the format of the properties and try again.

Also after tracing the correlation id from the ULS Log I get the error below. I have tried several things and still no luck including this [link](http://sharepoint.sureshc.com/2017/01/one-of-properties-of-web-part-has-incorrect-format.html) which is exactly the same issue I am facing but can not seem to find anything that relates to the frames the author mentioned in the html for my masterpage.

On trying to open the Page Layout too I get the same exact error. Please I need help resolving any pointers would be appreciated.

Other Observations

1. Only logged on users get this error and anonymous users do not get this error.

   2. The CEWP is not on the master page, but unable to view the pages in question as any attempt to open this up in Code View in Sharepoint Designer I get the same error.
   3. The issues was not happening before now but just stated recently.

*

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation cannot deserialize the Web Part.  Check the format of the properties and try again. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (9, 45). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance validation error: '                                      None                                  ' is not a valid value for FrameType.    
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderContentEditorWebPart.Read7_FrameType(String s)    
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderContentEditorWebPart.Read12_ContentEditorWebPart(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)    
 at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderContentEditorWebPart.Read13_WebPart()     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.ParseXml(XmlReader reader, Type type, String[] links, SPWeb spWeb)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.ParseXml(XmlReader reader, Type type, String[] links, SPWeb spWeb)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.AddParsedSubObject(Object obj)    
 at ASP._15_f21aa35e_78ad_443e_918e_d93a6d85de72_330623065.__BuildControl__control57()    
 at ASP._15_f21aa35e_78ad_443e_918e_d93a6d85de72_330623065.__BuildControl__control48()    
 at ASP._15_f21aa35e_78ad_443e_918e_d93a6d85de72_330623065.__BuildControlSPHtmlTag()    
 at ASP._15_f21aa35e_78ad_443e_918e_d93a6d85de72_330623065.__BuildControlTree(_15_f21aa35e_78ad_443e_918e_d93a6d85de72_330623065 __ctrl)    
 at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

*

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint 2013 RTM environment, I add the content editor web part as the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-add-a-web-part-zone-snippet-in-sharepoint).

I receive the same error as yours.

Then if I add the script editor web part, there is no such error.

So, you could add script editor web part instead of content editor web part.

And per my test in my SharePoint 2013 with December 2017 CU, I add the content editor web part, there is no such error, but it displays like the picture below.
[image]

So, the error “One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation cannot reserialize the Web Part. Check the format of the properties and try again.” is fixed if you install the latest CU for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: but this has been working until recently so I wondering what is causing it, another thing is it works for anonymous users but when logged in the error returns.

Comment: You could consider installing the latest CU for SharePoint 2013.